# Generated ASP table add buttons that pull row values

Tags: c#, asp.net

ok so I have this ASP:Table which pulls its rows of info from a stored procedure query, only two columns but wish to add a third with a button for each row that when clicked will grab the information in the prior columns for use in another function.

not sure how the hell to code it though as the buttons are generated per row and how can I programme events for a unknown number of buttons there must be a way of doing It programmatically.

```
               Table Header             
Datacolumn1 Datacolumn2     
a           2              Select
b           4              Select
e           9              Select
```

so when I press select on the second row it gives me string1=b string2=4

I imagine the code would look something like this (not likely but in a ideal world :D)

```
protected void select_row (eventargs as e)
{
  string data1 = Row(e).cell(0).text
  int data2 = Row(e).cell(1).text
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a grid like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid1" runat="server" onrowcommand="Grid1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Datacolumn1" HeaderText="Data column1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Datacolumn2" HeaderText="Data column2" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="SelectIt" Text="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Datacolumn1") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Use RowCommand event

```
  protected void Grid1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (Button)e.CommandSource ;
        if (e.CommandName == "SelectIt")
        {
            var Row =(GridViewRow) btn.NamingContainer;
            var Datacolumn1 = Row.Cells[0].Text;
            var Datacolumn2 = Row.Cells[1].Text;

            btn.Text = "selected: " + Datacolumn1 + "," + Datacolumn2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic, was just about to edit to say id gone to gridview for the paging but beat me to it thanks!